# replace the duplicated sentences with word "same"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, duplicates

I would like to change the repeated comments with word "same" but keep the original ones and change the ID like below. However, some comments are not matched exactly such as the last three.

```
df = {'Key': ['111', '111','111', '222*1','222*2', '333*1','333*2', '333*3','444','444', '444'],
      'id' : ['', '','', '1','2', '1','2', '3','', '','',],
        'comment': ['wrong sentence', 'wrong sentence','wrong sentence', 'M','M', 'F','F', 'F','wrong sentence used in the topic', 'wrong sentence used','wrong sentence use']}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

print(df)
```

the input :

[image]

Desired output  :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ind = df['comment'].str.contains('wrong sentence')

def my_func(x):
    if len(x['comment'].values[0]) > 1 and len(x) > 1 and ind[x.index[0]]:
        df.loc[x.index[1:], 'comment'] = 'same'
        df.loc[x.index, 'id'] = range(1, len(x)+1)

df.groupby('Key').apply(my_func)

print(df)
```

Output

```
      Key id                           comment
0     111  1                    wrong sentence
1     111  2                              same
2     111  3                              same
3   222*1  1                                 M
4   222*2  2                                 M
5   333*1  1                                 F
6   333*2  2                                 F
7   333*3  3                                 F
8     444  1  wrong sentence used in the topic
9     444  2                              same
10    444  3                              same
```

Here, [contains](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) is used to match 'wrong sentence'. The result is a boolean mask.

[Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) is applied on the 'Key' column, the grouping result is passed to the user-defined function: `my_func`. Where the conditions are checked string is greater than 1, strings greater than 1 and matches the word 'wrong sentence'.

[loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is used to reset values.

**Update**

```
def my_func(x):
    unic = x['comment'].str.slice(start=0, stop=10).value_counts().values[0]
    clv = len(x)
    if len(x['comment'].values[0]) > 1 and clv > 1 and unic == clv:
        df.loc[x.index[1:], 'comment'] = 'same'
        df.loc[x.index, 'id'] = range(1, clv+1)

df.groupby('Key').apply(my_func)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But This solution works just if the comment has " wrong sentence" I did not mean to repeated it again in index 8-10. I just wanted to know how to deal with uncompleted sentences. Assume index 8 is " right thing used in the topic " then index 9 " right thing used" so on

Comment: I wanted a logic that test through the entire column and check if the first 10 characters matched then replace it with "same"

Comment: you need to apply: df['comment'].str.slice(start=0, stop=10)

Comment: You mean should change ind in your code into ind= df['comment'].str.slice(start=0, stop=10) ?

Comment: Updated on each grouping, the number of unique rows is obtained. The string is taken from 0 to 10. If the number of unique matches the total, then it turns out what is expected.

Comment: if you want to check for a word of at least 10 letters, then you need to change:len(x['comment'].values[0]) >= 10

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#test first 10 values for duplicates and no `M,F` values
m = df['comment'].str[:10].duplicated(keep=False) & ~df['comment'].isin(['M','F'])
#create consecutive groups only for matched mask and create counter
counter = df.groupby((~m).cumsum().where(m)).cumcount().add(1)

#assign counter only for matched rows
df.loc[m, 'id'] = counter[m]

#assign same for duplicates - it means if counter values greater like 1
df.loc[counter.gt(1) & m, 'comment'] = 'same'
print (df)
      Key id                           comment
0     111  1                    wrong sentence
1     111  2                              same
2     111  3                              same
3   222*1  1                                 M
4   222*2  2                                 M
5   333*1  1                                 F
6   333*2  2                                 F
7   333*3  3                                 F
8     444  1  wrong sentence used in the topic
9     444  2                              same
10    444  3                              same
```

If need also test duplicates per `Key` groups:

```
m = df['comment'].str[:10].duplicated(keep=False) & ~df['comment'].isin(['M','F'])
counter = df.groupby(['Key',(~m).cumsum().where(m)]).cumcount().add(1)

df.loc[m, 'id'] = counter[m]
df.loc[counter.gt(1) & m, 'comment'] = 'same'
print (df)
      Key id                           comment
0     111  1                    wrong sentence
1     111  2                              same
2     111  3                              same
3   222*1  1                                 M
4   222*2  2                                 M
5   333*1  1                                 F
6   333*2  2                                 F
7   333*3  3                                 F
8     444  1  wrong sentence used in the topic
9     444  2                              same
10    444  3                              same
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But This solution works just if the comment has " wrong sentence" I did not mean to repeated it again in index 8-10. I just wanted to know how to deal with uncompleted sentences. Assume index 8 is " right thing used in the topic "  then index 9 " right thing used" so on

Comment: @AAA - How is possible identify wrong sentence? Is possible change `m = df['comment'].str.contains('wrong sentence')` to `m = ~df['comment'].isin(['M','F'])`, in another words consecutive non values `M, F` ?

Comment: I wanted a logic that test through the entire column and check if the first 10 characters matched then replace it with "same"

Comment: @AAA - How is possible distinguish duplicated good sentences and bad sentences? Because if filter first 10 letters `print(df['comment'].str[:10])` match also M, F (good data) and all another rows (bad data)

Comment: It is fine to match all including M & F

Comment: @AAA Can you test in real data `m = ~df['comment'].isin(['M','F'])` instead `m = df['comment'].str.contains('wrong sentence')` ?

Comment: @AAA - Or change to `m = df['comment'].str[:10].duplicated(keep=False) & ~df['comment'].isin(['M','F'])` ?